# How to keep shared data without using singleton in Xamarin.forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, singleton

I have a `ContentPage` with a `ListView`. I'm navigating to this content page using another content page's button. This button shows the list item count. I have `ViewModel` connected to each content page. I can update the count when add items to my `ObservableCollection` since field is adding not from the list page. But when I delete an item from the list view, I want to update the count in that time as well. How can I keep this `ObservableCollection` as a shared one between these 2 `ContentPAges`? I know using a`Singleton` class we can do this. But since my code should support for unit testing it seems I cannot do this.

What is the best way to make this `ObservableCollection` shared among these content pages?

Comment: Passing a reference of ObservableCollection to PageB should do the trick in a very simple scenario. How does PageB knows how many items are in the list currently?

Comment: @EvZ In first Page I have an ObservableCollection and when items added I get the collection count. For this I have used a singleton class to keep the collection. But I want to avoid this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the only information you are wanting to share is the actual count of the items in the list, you could use the MessagingService that is build in in Xamarin Forms.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/messaging-center

So in your example maybe create a class that holds all the info that you want to share and in one page do a

```
MessagingCenter.Send<ShareInfo>(...)
```

So you can pass data.

And in the other page do

```
MessagingCenter.Subscribe<ShareInfo>(...)
```

To receive the data and use that to update the button count.

Comment: Worth mentioning that `Unsubscribing` is also required.

Comment: eww..Did you just recommend using the Messaging Service? I'd rather write VB code

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you need a single data repository to be shared between multiple `ViewModels`. Which means that you need to keep a single instance of the repository somewhere in your code base. Depends on your project setup this repository can live in the IOC container or as a simple property within the `App` class or elsewhere. Also, depends on the collection data type you also may need to persist the data to SQL, local storage or etc. This way it will be trivial to access the collection from any ViewModel in the application.

However, since I don't understand your intents fully, there might be other solutions. Like passing the reference of the collection to the next page and etc.